# Testing Grails taglibs that call other taglibs

Tags: grails, gsp, taglib

Say I've got two taglibs, `Foo` which does something specific for a particular part of my application, and `Util` which is shared across the whole thing. I want to do something like this:

```
class UtilTagLib {
    def utilTag = { attrs -> 
        ...
    }
}

class FooTagLib {
    def fooTag = {
        ...
        out << g.utilTag(att1: "att1", att2: "att2")
        ...
    }
}
```

However, when I do this, and try to run my unit test for `fooTag()`, I get:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.utilTag() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[att1:att1, att2:att2]]

I tried giving `UtilTagLib` its own namespace

```
static namespace = "util"
```

and changing the call to

```
out << util.utilTag(...)
```

but this just gets me

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: util for class: org.example.FooTagLib

Possibly also of note: In the log, I see:

> WARN - Bean named 'groovyPagesUriService' is missing.

Obviously, `UtilTagLib` isn't getting created and injected correctly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: add the call

```
mockTagLib UtilTagLib
```

to the `setUp()` (or `@Before`) method of the test case. This is a method on [GroovyPageUnitTestMixin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/mixin/web/GroovyPageUnitTestMixin.html#mockTagLib%28java.lang.Class%29) that, somewhat counterintuitively, instantiates the specified tag library -- the real one, not a mock -- and wires it into the Grails application context. It's used internally to set up the actual taglib under test (in this case `FooTagLib`), but it also works to set up additional collaborator tag libs.

Note that this isn't perfect, since it makes it more of an integration test than a pure unit test -- ideally we *would* be using a mock `UtilTagLib` and just testing the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to refactor the line:

```
out << g.utilTag(att1: "att1", att2: "att2")
```

in to its own method, say "renderUtilTag(...)", then mock that out in the unit test, e.g.:

```
FooTagLib.metaClass.renderUtilTag = { /* something */ }
```

That way you're testing the functionality of FooTagLib only in the unit test, with no dependency on UtilTagLib.

Comment: I suppose, but the point is kind of to make sure that FooTagLib is correctly interoperating with UtilTagLib.